# kotlin - realm and parcel

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I develop the android project with android studio.
I want to save realm objects using `onSaveInstanceState()` in kotlin.
My code is

```
@Parcel( implementations = arrayOf(UserRealmProxy::class),
         value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
         analyze = arrayOf(User::class))
open class User : RealmObject() {
    open var name: String? = null

    @ParcelPropertyConverter(ListParcelConverter::class)
    open var Items: RealmList<Item>? = null
}
```

but there are some errors while compiling:

```
'Unresolved reference: UserRealmProxy'
'An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant'
```

Sure, UserRealmProxy exists already because already the project has been compiled.
also `@ParcelPropertyConverter(ListParcelConverter::class)` does not work.
it causes exception in runtime:

```
'java.io.NotSerializableException: io.realm.RealmList'
```

But this code is compiled well in java.

i need your help.

Comment: Do you **need** to parcel instead of requerying the object?

Comment: First I got the same message `Unresolved reference: UserRealmProxy` but it disappear after building the project.

Comment: Can you try `@field:ParcelPropertyConverter(ListParcelConverter::class)` instead of `@ParcelPropertyConverter(ListParcelConverter::class)`?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: same issue here.. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you will annotate to **setter**. Please try this.

```
@Parcel( implementations = arrayOf(UserRealmProxy::class),
     value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
     analyze = arrayOf(User::class))
open class User : RealmObject() {
    open var name: String? = null
    open var Items: RealmList<Item>? = null
    @ParcelPropertyConverter(ListParcelConverter::class) set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I have this error: 'Unresolved reference: UserRealmProxy'. If I have this package: com.path.model.Album, and I have to use:

```
import io.realm.com_path_model_AlbumRealmProxy

...
@Parcel(implementations = arrayOf(com_path_model_AlbumRealmProxy::class)
```